# How to COLOR lower-roman ordered list style in html with just css?

Tags: html, list, css, layout

Getting something as simple as the example image below to work, proves to be very difficult. My frustration comes from the fact that after all these years, this is still not possible easily with html/css only, which is what I want! ***I want an ordered list with colored roman-style bullets!*** And having the text stay neatly put together exactly as the example below. I've tried numerous efforts with fiddle but I can't get it to look as neat as my image below. Any clues how to improve this?

```
ol{
 counter-reset:item;
 list-style:none;
}
ol li:before{
 content: counter(item, lower-roman) "."; color: #4000ff;
 counter-increment: item;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: right;
 padding-right: 4px;


}ol li{
 text-indent: -20px;
 margin: 4px 0 0 17px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MEBxA/89/

*PS While I was writing some abcd placeholder text in indesign, suddenly my imagination took off...*

---

[image]

---

Whats needed:

1. Achieve proper gap between roman letters and li text. SUCCESS!
2. Add left or right alignment of the roman letters
3. Have the next-up lines fit neatly aligned. SUCCESS!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I hope that I understand correctly. You already got the list-type coloured, so the only problem is the alignment?

Drop the `text-indent` and left margin on the `li` and add a negative `margin-right` to the `li:before`:

```
ol li:before{
 content: counter(item, lower-roman) "."; 
 color: #4000ff;
 counter-increment: item;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: right;
 margin-left: -30px;
}
ol li{

 margin: 4px 0 0 0;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MEBxA/90/)

Comment: Thanks Awesome! final question: would it be possible to have the lower-roman letters align right instead of left (they are currently left aligned)